# Allow generation of asynchronous operations disable

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I am developing one windows phone app. I have created one **WCF** application. I have added `Service Reference`. I want to disable `asynchronous operations` in it's configuration. By default it show's me enable.

[image: Configure Service]

How can I disable **Allow generation of asynchronous operations**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Silverlight/WP doesn't allow synchronous calls to WCF services, only generation of asynchronous operations is available.

Comment: I have this same problem while using WCF with Xamarin.  It seams the .NET Portable library I am using doesn't allow synchronous calls either.