# asmx service work regular but not async

Tags: c#, xamarin, asmx

I am using remote asmx service with c# .net project and it works just fine.
When I try to consume the same service by visual studio generated classes in a xamarin project it generates async->completed methods and it crashes the api generating error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I would have tried to consume it any other way but hats the only way vs created the service classes.

Any ideas?
update: i tracked the error from the server and it tunes out it doesn't receive any parameters!

Answer (score 1):

You should tweak around the service reference builder. Click `Advanced` then, make sure `Allow generation of asynchronous operations` not checked. Only with  this generation method you wont get those async methods.

[image]
[image]

Comment: actually this is not allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426872/allow-generation-of-asynchronous-operations-disable